# Database hierarchy for timesheet day locking

Tags: database-design, laravel-4

I'm creating a timesheet web application but for now I came to a blocking point.

My "times" table looks like this:
*(taken from my laravel framework migration code)*

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->timestamps();
$table->datetime('start_date');
$table->float('hours')->default('8');
$table->text('description')->nullable();
$table->boolean('locked');
$table->integer('project_id')->unsigned();
```

The idea is that one of our supervisors would be able to lock on weekly basis.
Should I just add a simple **lock boolean field** ? or maybe create a second table called week_agenda (or some better naming) and add the locks there?

Regards

Comment: I would create a datetime column that holds the datetime that the timesheet is locked.  I would want to capture that data anyway, so it would kill two birds with one stone.  I would also capture the id of the person doing the locking.

Comment: Okay So just have a **locked_at** datetime field instead of boolean. But as for querying and validation (as for example a user may not add/edit dates before the last lock date) isn't this a heavy load? Is it a good idea to use _SELECT * FROM times ORDER BY locked_at DESC LIMIT 1_?

Comment: @Goowik If you have an index on locked_at, the load is minimal. If you don't have a corresponding index, the load would indeed be quite heavy provided you have a larger number of rows in your table.